# Cut string from command output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, logs, sensors

I would like to cut `150.8` from this string `temp1:       +150.8°F   (crit = +197.6°F)`.  Here is my script for logging temperatures with the command `sensors`:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")    # get current date
now_excel=$(date +"%D %H:%M")    # get current date & time in excel format

file_dir="/var/www/html/logs"
file="$file_dir/logging_$now.csv"    # backup name and directory

temp=$(sensors -Af | sed -n '2{p;q}')    # temp1:       +150.8°F  (crit = +197.6°F)
#temp_num="$temp" | sed 's/+\(.*\)°/\1/g'

# add line to csv
printf "$now_excel" >> "$file"
printf ", " >> "$file"
printf "$temp" >> "$file"
printf "\n" >> "$file"

find "$file_dir"/* -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;    # remove any backup files older than 3 days

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using sed

Here is one way:

```
$ sensors -Af | sed -n '2{s/°.*//; s/[^+-]*//; p; q}'
+105.8
```

Or, using the same command inside *command substitution* to capture its output in a variable:

```
temp=$(sensors -Af | sed -n '2{s/°.*//; s/[^+-]*//; p; q}')
```

`s/°.*//` removes the first occurrence of the degree symbol, `°`, and everything after it.  `s/[^+-]*//` removes everything up to but not including the first `+` or `-`.

#### Using awk

```
$ sensors -Af | awk 'NR==2{print $3+0; exit;}'
105.8
```

The number that we want is in the third field.  Because the third field contains characters, for example `+105.8°F`, we add `0` to it.  This forces awk to convert it to what we want: a number.

Comment: Assuming (pretty safely) that the temperature is above zero.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ha!  For those working in the arctic, the answer is now updated to allow for negative temperatures.

Comment: +1.  the `sed` version should use `[FC]` instead of just `F`.  most of the world uses celsius/centigrade rather than fahrenheit.

Comment: @cas Good point.  I updated to eliminate F and C.